# how to give "same as the above" in form entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form method="POST" class="form-group">
 <label>First Name</label><input type="text" name="FName" class="form-control">
 <label>Last Name</label><input type="text" name="LName" class="form-control"><br>
 <label>I am Ready</label><input type="checkbox" name="ch"><br><br>
 <label>Address</label><input type="text" name="Address" class="form-control">
</form><br><br>

<form method="POST" class="form-group">
 <label>Same as Above</label><input type="checkbox" name="chd"><br><br>
 <label>First Name</label><input type="text" name="FName" class="form-control">
 <label>Last Name</label><input type="text" name="LName" class="form-control"><br>
 <label>I am Ready</label><input type="checkbox" name="ch"><br><br>
 <label>Address</label><input type="text" name="Address" class="form-control">
</form>
```

when we checked the checkbox named 'same as the above' then the second form will have to take same values that are in the first form fields.

Comment: Using the tools you've indicated (JavaScript/jQuery), you would identify the fields that you're copying from and get their values then identify the fields you're copying to and set their values.  What have you tried?

Comment: do you just want to copy the values from form1 to form2 ?

Comment: i believe you have 2 same form inside your code and i know you shouldn't give the same names elements inside HTML. First please change those names and give your form label's id's. Then you can copy what form 1 says to form 2

Comment: @warl0ck  yes, i just want to copy the values from form1 to form2..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery like suppose you have 2 input fields and a checkbox
if you click on checkbox it has to get value from first input and assign it to second like

```js
$(function(){
  ("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){     
    var input1=$("#input1").val();
    $("#input2").val(input1);
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: I hope this works fine for few fields but it not seems better for more fields so i need to write code again and again with every field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start listening on proto form fields changes if "same as above" checked and stop listening if unchecked. And when value of any field changes then just proxy values of all proto form fields to surrogate form fields

```
(function($) {
  var $forms = $('form');
  var $protoForm = $forms.eq(0);
  var $surrogateForm = $forms.eq(1);

  var proxyValues = function(name) {
    var $fields = $protoForm.find('input');

    if (typeof name === 'string') {
      $fields = $fields.filter('[name="' + name + '"]');
    }

    $fields.each(function() {
      var field = $surrogateForm.find('[name="' + name + '"]').get(0);
      if (field.type === 'checkbox') {
        field.checked = this.checked;
      } else {
        field.value = this.value;
      }
    });
  };

  var startValuesProxy = function() {
    proxyValues();
    $protoForm.on('change.valuesProxy', 'input', function(e) {
      proxyValues(e.target.name);
    });
  };

  var stopValuesProxy = function() {
    $protoForm.off('.valuesProxy');
  };

  $surrogateForm.on('change', '[name="chd"]', function(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      startValuesProxy();
    } else {
      stopValuesProxy();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you for your response,  your answer is little complex, i didn't understood properly as i am beginner in jquery. is there any simple logic for this..?..

Comment: This logic is complex because it will proxy values any time any field in first form changed and not only once when you check the "same as above" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

1) When You check the checkbox, which would mean you would need to create a hidden field on your Address form, and have the results of the address form fields that you require passed to the hidden fields on the address form.

2) On Checked Box Checked Event. [`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirenpateldev/fj7eufkg/1/)

Hope Its Work !!!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can just disable the controls - seems to be that way on other sites - then in your submit method - if the checkbox is clicked - send that to the controller and use the 'above' values there too..

```
$(function() {
    $('#chkSameAsAbove').on('change', function() {
     var otherControls = $(this).parent().find('input:not(#chkSameAsAbove)');
         if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            otherControls.prop('disabled', true); 
         } else {
         otherControls.prop('disabled', false); 
         }
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xv5bv4h/

Comment: i tried with your logic, it only disables the second form fields but it will not take values that are in the first form. i want first form values to be inserted in second form after checking the checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

Get all the inputs in javascript.
Let's say you have two input fields and one checkbox, if checkbox is checked both field will have same value, if not user will enter second value in second input.

so lets try this code:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
if (document.getElementById('checkbox_field_ID').checked) {
        $('#input2').append(input1);
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This code will move input1 from its original place to destination instead of updating value.